# Are those articles before nouns really matters for common communications?

Tags: articles

I had a sentence:

> It is so weird that same markdown context can paste image in
>   "description" area, but "comments" area is not.

I used the 'Grammarly' extension in the Chrome browser, then it warns many article errors:

- The "image" should correct to "the image".
- The "description" should correct to "the description".
- The "comments" should correct to "the comments".

Alright, I know it is right.
I believe the reader can absolutely understand the meaning precisely, same as those translation software.
But I wonder that is the native writer would insert each article for the grammar correctness?

Comment: This sentence seems incorrect to me; I can only make something of it by looking at it as an exclamation (with small modifications): "It is so weird that the same markdown context can paste an/the image in a/the "description" area, but not in the "comments!". Is that what is meant?

Comment: Don't trust Grammarly. Grammarly is correct that the sentence is wrong, but all its suggested corrections are wrong. It should read *It is so weird that the same markdown context can paste an image in the "description" area, but not the "comments" area.*

Comment: @PeterShor The Grammarly suggests me for the "image" 2 corrections actually: "the image" and "an image". So your suggestion is in one of its corrections. I compared your corrections with the Grammarly, it looks like almost the same, right? Why you say its corrections are wrong, too?

Comment: @LPH Oh my. So those articles are really matters, right? They seem can result in "incorrect" state/feeling to native readers. In the beginning, I guess that simplified them only simplified the "looks" itself, not realization. But it seems to affects more.

Comment: it shouldn't be *"the description" area* but *the "description" area*. But maybe I misunderstood your description of their corrections.